# スプレッドシートにcsvを読み込む

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, csv, google-spreadsheet

ローカルにダウンロードしてあるcsvファイルをスプレッドシートに読み込またいです。

デバッグをしても特にエラーは表示されないのですが、dialog.htmlからcsvを指定しても何も反応がありません。

お気づきの点ありましたら指摘いただけると助かります。
ご存知の方おりましたらどうぞ宜しくお願いいたします。

---

**サーバー側のコード.gs**

```js
function showDialog(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "CSVアップロード");
}

function uploadCsv(form) {  
  var blob = form.myFile;
  var csvText = blob.getDataAsString();    
  var values = Utilities.parseCsv(csvText);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

**ダイアログを作成するHTMLファイルdialog.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <input name="myFile" type="file">
      <button onclick="uploadCsv(this.parentNode);">アップロード</button> 
    </form>
    
    <script>
      function uploadCsv(form) {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(){
          google.script.host.close();
        }).uploadCsv(form);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @himenonさん　ありがとうございます。

Comment: もしもV8 runtimeを使用した状態でgoogle.script.runを使用してファイルのアップロードを行いたい場合は、例えばデータをbyte配列やbase64などに変換することで動作させることも可能です。英語で恐縮ですが [参考](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60742695/7108653)

Comment: @Tanaike さん、有難うございます！参考に致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

スクリプトエディタ＞実行から"chrome v8を搭載した新しいApp Scriptを無効にする"にしたところ
無事csvを読み込める様になりました。