# csvをスプレッドシートにUTF-8で取り込みたい

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

ローカルにあるCSVファイルがSHIFT-JISで保存されるため、Googleスプレッドシートに取り込む際文字化けしてしまいます。

[以前行った関連質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/71511) にて教えて頂いた以下のGASスクリプトにUTF-8に変換するコードを追加することで対応できればと考えておりますが可能でしょうか。

```
function showDialog(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('dialog');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html, "CSVアップロード");
}

function uploadCsv(form) {  
  var blob = form.myFile;
  var csvText = blob.getDataAsString();    
  var values = Utilities.parseCsv(csvText);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

ご存知の方おりましたらとても助かります。
どうぞ宜しくお願いいたします。

Comment: この記事とかが、参考になるかも。[Googl Apps Scriptを使ってファイル読み込みからスプレッドシートに表示](https://pikucha.sakura.ne.jp/blog/2019/03/08/googl-apps-script%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E8%AA%AD%E3%81%BF%E8%BE%BC%E3%81%BF%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%B9%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%82%B7/)

Comment: @kunifさん　情報頂き有難うございます。試してみたのですが、csvを読み込んだ時点で文字化けになってしまいます。csvのスプレッドシート取り込みが結構手間がかかってしまうので、何とかこちらでも引き続き調べてまいります。

Answer (score 1):

getDataAsStringにshift-jisを設定するだけでした...
以下のコードで動作確認できました。
Apps Scriptランタイムは無効にしています。

```
function uploadCsv(form) {
    var blob = form.myFile;
    var csvText = blob.getDataAsString('shift-jis');
    var values = Utilities.parseCsv(csvText);
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```